# Вызов класса с класснеймом из переменной

Tags: php, ооп

```
$networksFiles = new \DirectoryIterator(__DIR__.'/networks');
$networkClasses = array();
foreach($networksFiles as $file)
    if ($file->isFile())
        $networkClasses[] = $file->getBasename('.php');

foreach($networkClasses as $class) {
    $instance = new $class();
    echo $instance->getNetworkName();
}
```

Приветствую, необходимо обойти все классы в папке и вывести значения метода. Если с получением классов проблем не возникло, то с созданием экземпляра класса  есть проблема.

Например при значении $class "CTwitter", страница упадет с ошибкой "Class 'CTwitter' not found", но при этом $instance = new CTwitter(); будет работать.

Comment: Вам необходимо задать функцию автозагрузчик классов

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.spl-autoload-register.php

Comment: @rjhdby Проблема не в том, что классы не загружены, они доступны для вызова. Проблема в синтаксисе вызова, если класнейм лежит в переменной.

Comment: Должно работать. Возможно где-то досадная опечатка. Попробуйте отдебажить таким образом, `var_dump($class);$i1=new $class();$i2=new RealName();` Подозреваю, что у вас в $class все же несколько не то, что вы ожидаете, либо все-же класс не подгружен